# Create a mount in Databricks using a Service Principal with read only permission

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I have to create a mount to a Storage Account in Databricks using a Service Principal.

The Service Principal has **Storage Blob Data Reader** permission on the storage account because Databricks needs to read the data but should not be possible to modify them.

On Databricks my code is:

```py
client_id = dbutils.secrets.get('key-vault', 'client-id')
secret = dbutils.secrets.get('key-vault', 'secret')
tenant_id = dbutils.secrets.get('key-vault', 'tenant-id')

configs = {
    "fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
    "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
    "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": client_id,
    "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": secret,
    "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token"
}

source = f"abfss://container-name@storage-account.dfs.core.windows.net"
mount_point = f"/mnt/mount-name"

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = source,
  mount_point = mount_point,
  extra_configs = configs
)
```

But I get the error:

```
An error occurred while calling o434.mount.
: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, HEAD,
```

All the secrets in the key vault are correct, so it seems that is not possible to create a mount having Storage Blob Data Reader grant on the storage account.

Am I correct? Is there a way to achieve this without giving Contributor grant?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's trying to initialize the filesystem. Try with the following entry added to the `configs` dict:

```
"fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization": "false"
```